# Dedupe delimited text in a SQL column

Tags: sql

Just gave a thought about this case, where a column with data 'A,B,C,D,A,B,E,D' should be deduped as 'A,B,C,D,E'. I can think of doing this in two steps by splitting the delimited values, deduping and restitching. I am not sure if there is any easy way to achieve this and am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: You should fix your data structure and not store lists of values as strings.  Each value should be on a separate row in a junction table.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why storing CSV data in a column is a bad idea in general: it makes it very hard to work with your data.  The best long term fix for you would be to normalize your data.

Comment: I agree and this is not a real case. Just wanted to know if there is anything to solve this.

Comment: Questions: which DB are you using and can you guarantee that the letters are always sorted alphabetically?

Comment: This is in WX2 (ANSI SQL) and the data is not presorted.

Comment: I was going to suggest a regex, but for that to have any chance, we'd need some kind of fixed structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server I would do something like this (based on [this article](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql.html)):

```
DECLARE @TEXT nvarchar(400) = 'A,B,A,C,D,B,D';
DECLARE @DEDUPTEXT nvarchar(400);
WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
AS(
    SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(',',@text) AS endpos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(',',@text,endpos+1)
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
)
SELECT @DEDUPTEXT = COALESCE(@DEDUPTEXT+ ',', '') + [Data] 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
    'Data' = SUBSTRING(@text,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@text)+1)-stpos)
FROM Split ) dedup

SELECT @DEDUPTEXT
```

It does basically what you have already described in your question.
Not sure if that could be helpful for you, feel free to downvote - I will delete it eventually.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating the answer. I am still open for other ways